# LINQ Where with AND OR condition

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, where-clause

So I have managed to get this query working

```
List<string> listStatus = new List<string>() ; 
listStatus.add("Text1");

List<string> listMerchants = new List<string>() ;
listMerchants.add("Text2");


from item in db.vw_Dropship_OrderItems
             where listStatus.Contains(item.StatusCode) 
                      && listMerchants.Contains(item.MerchantId)
             select item;
```

Here I would like to check if listStatus and listMerchants are not null only then put them inside WHERE clause.

Like

if listMerchants is null then query will be like

```
     where listStatus.Contains(item.StatusCode)
```

I do not want to use switch or If condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
from item in db.vw_Dropship_OrderItems
    where (listStatus != null ? listStatus.Contains(item.StatusCode) : true) &&
    (listMerchants != null ? listMerchants.Contains(item.MerchantId) : true)
    select item;
```

Might give strange behavior if both listMerchants and listStatus are both null.

Comment: I had to do listStatus.Count == 0 instead of null

Answer (score 9):

Well, you're going to have to check for null somewhere. You could do something like this:

```
from item in db.vw_Dropship_OrderItems
         where (listStatus == null || listStatus.Contains(item.StatusCode)) 
            && (listMerchants == null || listMerchants.Contains(item.MerchantId))
         select item;
```

Answer (score 6):

Linq With Or Condition by using Lambda expression you can do as below

```
DataTable dtEmp = new DataTable();

dtEmp.Columns.Add("EmpID", typeof(int));
dtEmp.Columns.Add("EmpName", typeof(string));
dtEmp.Columns.Add("Sal", typeof(decimal));
dtEmp.Columns.Add("JoinDate", typeof(DateTime));
dtEmp.Columns.Add("DeptNo", typeof(int));

dtEmp.Rows.Add(1, "Rihan", 10000, new DateTime(2001, 2, 1), 10);
dtEmp.Rows.Add(2, "Shafi", 20000, new DateTime(2000, 3, 1), 10);
dtEmp.Rows.Add(3, "Ajaml", 25000, new DateTime(2010, 6, 1), 10);
dtEmp.Rows.Add(4, "Rasool", 45000, new DateTime(2003, 8, 1), 20);
dtEmp.Rows.Add(5, "Masthan", 22000, new DateTime(2001, 3, 1), 20);


var res2 = dtEmp.AsEnumerable().Where(emp => emp.Field<int>("EmpID")
            == 1 || emp.Field<int>("EmpID") == 2);

foreach (DataRow row in res2)
{
    Label2.Text += "Emplyee ID: " + row[0] + "   &   Emplyee Name: " + row[1] + ",  ";
}
```