# How to use inner join in linq query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have used a variable called as `"Filter"`
filter will be having inner join with other table. for example

Filter = `"inner join tb1 on tbl1 = vCatalogItemsDetails"`

My main query is

```
var result = context.vCatalogItemsDetails
.Where(whereClause) // whereClause will have all where conditions
.OrderBy("itemID descending select context.vCatalogItemsDetails")
.Skip((pageN - 1) * 10).Take(10);
```

how can i use the variable `"Filter"` in the above query so that i can get inner join ?

Comment: I see no indication here that you have attempted this and are struggling. Did you try looking this up? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098041/linq-join-with-filter-criteria

Comment: you must use filter in where clause

Answer (score 1):

Your filter shouldn't join tables.

You should join your tables (to minimal joined size) and use Where conditions on the result. Linq should optimize it for you.

The Where conditions may have several 'And' expressions in it:
[LINQ Where with AND OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719488/linq-where-with-and-or-condition)